# What Bracha acharona on .5 kezayit of grapes eaten together with .5 kezayit of mezonot crackers?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements

What Bracha acharona on .5 kezayit of grapes eaten together with .5 kezayit of mezonot crackers?

Do you say al hamichya ve'al haetz or is it boreh nefashot since neither is a kezayit?

Please provide a reason with your answer.

Comment: As a separate question but I will add it here, if I eat a whole portion of mezonot and half a portion of eitz, so i have to say al hamichya, can i throw in "eitz" as part of the same b'racha as I won't be making a separate one?

Answer (score 6):

*Baer Heitev* to [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 210:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1038) writes:

> מכזית. כל האוכלין מצטרפין לכזית אכל חצי זית מז' המינין וחצי זית אחר
>   מברך אחריהן בנ''ר.‏
>
> All foods combine for a "כזית," (therefore if) one ate half a זית from
>   the ז' מינים, and half a זית from something else, he makes a בורא
>   נפשות after.

This above case would be exactly your case -- a grape is one of the ז' מינים.

However, later in that same piece, he warns that

> ואם אכל מעט וחזר ואכל מעט אם שהה יותר מכא''פ אין מצטרף לברכה אחרונה
>
> If he ate (less than a זית), and then continued to eat after that,
>   more than a כדי אכילת פרס, then these foods do not combine for a ברכה
>   אחרונה.

(*translations mine*)

Therefore, it would appear that you do make a בורא נפשות in the case mentioned in your question, but then only if you ate both items within a כדי אכילת פרס.

---

Please note that my above assumptions may be incorrect, as the *Baer Heitev* may actually refer to something that naturally has the *bracha acharona* of *borei nefashos*, and not *mezonos*.

However, Fred [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52567/what-bracha-acharona-on-5-kezayit-of-grapes-eaten-together-with-5-kezayit-of-m/52569?noredirect=1#comment138196_52569) that the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch writes ([51](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0050_L2):4):

> וְנִרְאֶה לִי, דְּהוּא הַדִּין אִם אָכַל כַּחֲצִי זַיִת מִפֵּרוֹת
>   שֶׁמְבָרְכִין לְאַחֲרֵיהֶן עַל הָעֵץ, וְכַחֲצִי זַיִת מִמִּין
>   שֶׁמְבָרְכִין לְאַחֲרָיו עַל הַמִּחְיָה אוֹ כַּחֲצִי זַיִת פַּת מִכָּל
>   מָקוֹם מְבָרֵךְ לְאַחֲרֵיהֶן בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת רַבּוֹת.‏
>
> It would appear to me, that it would be the same in a case where one
>   ate half a זית of fruit whose ברכה אחרונה is "*al haetz*," and half a
>   זית of food that gets an *al hamichya*, or even bread, on would still
>   make the bracha of *borei nefashos* afterward.

However, [Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Zalman_Auerbach) rules (*Moriah*, Nissan 5752; also cited in [sam's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52570/5323)) that one should make two *brachos acharonos*, one *al hamichya* and one *v'al ha'eitz*.

Comment: It seems likely that the *Ba'eir Heiteiv* is talking about a case where one of the food items is a type that normally requires *borei n'fashos*, which is not the case in the OP.

Comment: On a second read, I think you're right. What do you think I should do to fix that in my answer?

Comment: Well, the *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* (51:4) explicitly concludes in accordance with your answer (using the language of "נראה לי"), so I suppose you can mention that, though R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach explicitly rules against your answer (in the Nissan 5752 issue of *Moriah*, as mentioned in Sam's answer).

Comment: Sure thing, but note that [Sam mentioned](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52570) both of those sources before I did. :)

Comment: "However, Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach rules (Moriah, Nissan 5752; also cited in sam's answer) that one should make two brachos acharonos, one al hamichya and one v'al ha'eitz." Why would you make two Berachoth instead of one joint Berachah?

Comment: @SethJ Good question. I don't know; this was quoted to me by sam and Fred. The "please provide a reason" part of the question was edited in after I answered.

Comment: How can rabbi auerbach say that if neither item was a kezayit?

Comment: I don't know, @AniYodeya. Fred gave me the citation, I haven't seen it, myself.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Feinhandler in his Sefer Avnei Yashfei 5:40 brings this exact case .He goes through the sources ,but I will write his psak ldinah. He holds("it seems") one should say al ahamchia and val haeitz, and so holds Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach  (see V'zot Habracha pg 45)

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 51:4 writes it seems the halacha in this case is one should say borei nefoshos. Rav Feinhandler addresses this kitzur in the tshuvah.